# Missing status icons in message/system tray

Tags: fedora, gnome3, icons

Some of my apps (such as Insync and Viber) do not show icons in the message tray (GNOME, Fedora 21). I can interact with them trough mouse clicks, but without icons it's difficult to tell if the files are sync'd and if I have any new messages.

I see that Insync' PNG icons are present in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/xx/status`

I've also tried the Topicons extension for GNOME, but no luck.

***Update 1***

I solved the issue with Insync by uninstalling insync-nautilus extension.